# References and footnotes

Tags: discussion

In my postings, I feel best when I post live sites or literature based references when I can. Is there a best-practice for this or is it not really considered even necessary?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I personally try to ensure answers are *self contained* of course but references back to sources are probably a great idea.

Consider the following though - sites do go down and your link might go stale. Be prepared to *maintain* the answer. Some folks link to the actual site and an internet archive cache should the former go down.

As for books - that's trickier. I *rarely* find situations when I need to reference them, and tend to favour google books. That said, amazon links are converted to SE referrals, and they make a little off it, so that's probably fine (and a way to support stackechange ;))

Comment: Yup. *Any* good answer *must* make sense on its own merits, so that's a good idea.